# product_id referenced in foreign key contstraint does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A product has many product images, and product image belongs to a product. Here is the schema

```
create_table "product_images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.boolean  "availability"
    t.text     "about"
    t.integer  "ref"
    t.string   "texture"
    t.string   "dimensions"
    t.string   "shipping"
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.string   "sizes",        default: [],              array: true
  end
```

Here are the models

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :product_images

end
```

I am trying to add a migration, to reference product_id as foreign key to product_images table

```
class AddForeignKeyToProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key :product_images, :products, column: :product_id
  end
end
```

Here is the error

```
== 20160705023021 AddForeignKeyToProductImages: migrating =====================
-- add_foreign_key(:product_images, :products, {:column=>:product_id})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "product_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "product_images" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_1c991d3be6"
FOREIGN KEY ("product_id")
  REFERENCES "products" ("id")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work:

```
rails g migration AddProductToProductImages

class AddProductToProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :product_images, :product_id, :integer
    add_foreign_key :product_images, :products
  end
end
```

You can also do the following:

```
rails g migration AddProductRefToProductImages product:references

class AddProductToProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :product_images, :product, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

You can check the [API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the "AddForeignKeyToProductImages" migration file. Then...

Run this command in the console:

```
rails g migration AddProductToProductImages product:references
```

Which should generate the following migration.

```
class AddProductToProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :product_images, :product, index: true
  end
end
```

Then Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`